# Como ordenar e filtrar consultas entre duas tabelas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tenho duas tabelas, uma de postagens (posts) e outra de amigos(friends). No meu *script* há uma área de *feed* aonde gostaria de apresentar as ultimas postagens dos amigos do usuário logado.

Porém em vez de de trazer as ultimas postagens por ordem, o resultado ordena a lista de amigos e o limite de postagens imposto na consulta da tabela "posts" trazendo essa quantia para cada usuário (amigo).

Explicando: O resultado traz por exemplo as 3 ultimas postagens de cada amigo, porém se eu tiver no sistema 4 amigos ele apresenta as três ultimas do primeiro (amigo), depois do segundo e assim por diante ao invés de três de cada mas ordenadas pelas ultimas.

Vi exemplos na internet mas não consegui entender a lógica de como fazer que a filtragem pela tabela "friends" não interfira na ordenação da exibição da tabela "posts".

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender isso? Grato.

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require "connect_db.php";

   $userID = $_SESSION['user_released'];

   $BuscaFriends = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userID LIKE '%$userID%'");
   $BuscaFriends->execute();
   if($BuscaFriends->rowCount() == ""){
?>

  <!-- Trecho HTML Caso não tenha amigos na tabela "friends" !!! -->

<?php
   }else{

   while($fetch = $BuscaFriends->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $idFriend = $fetch['friendID'];
      $statusFriend = $fetch['status'];

      $BuscaPost = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE autor LIKE '%$idFriend%' ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 3");
      $BuscaPost->execute();

      while($fetch = $BuscaPost->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $autor =  $fetch['autor'];
          $data =  $fetch['data'];
          $ava = $fetch['autor_avatar'];
          $msgID = $fetch['id'];
          $msg = $fetch['content'];

          $Verific = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user` = :user");
          $Verific->bindParam(':user', $autor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $Verific->execute();

          while($fatch = $Verific->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $user = $fatch['user'];
              $autorAvatar = $fatch['avatar'];
              $autorCover = $fatch['cover'];
          }
?>

   <!-- Trecho HTML que retorna resultados !!! -->

<?php
      }//Fecha "while" BuscaPost
   }//Fecha "while" BuscaFriends

   }//Fecho "else" amigos
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está fazendo um `select` para encontrar os amigos e depois fazendo outro `select` individual por amigo. Os resultados vêm ordenados por data, mas como é feita uma query para cada amigo, cada conjunto vem ordenado de acordo com os posts daquele amigo.

Você pode resolver isso tudo com um simples `join`:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
  JOIN friends f ON f.friendID = p.author
WHERE f.userID = 1
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

[Veja no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0a50e/2)

Essa query vai retornar todos os posts dos amigos do usuário de id `1`.

Caso queira também retornar as informações do amigo na mesma query, basta adicionar um `join` a tabela `user`:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name as author_name FROM posts p
  JOIN friends f ON f.friendID = p.author
  JOIN users u ON u.id = f.friendID
WHERE f.userID = 1
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

[Veja no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1386a7/1)

<sub>Como não sei a estrutura do seu banco fiz algo básico só pra você ter uma ideia.</sub>

Comment: Vi seu exemplo mais não sei como montar seu exemplo retorna erro de sintax...estou tentando padronizar minhas conexões com pdo quanto a minhas tabelas friendID não é um "id" más sim o nome de usário assim como userID...más cada entrada na tabela recebe um id (id int 11)

Comment: @LauroMoraes É só você ajustar a sintaxe pra ficar de acordo com a estrutura do seu banco. A lógica é exatamente a mesma.

Comment: De fato não conhecia JOIN segui seu exemplo e consegui encaixar agora pude entender essa correlação